# Function meant to send data to Redis server sends the data, but will not send success response

Tags: node.js, redis

My setJWT function sends a key/value pair to my local Redis server.  I've confirmed the data is set with the redis-cli tool.  However, the console.log("setJWT success") and res.json(response); in the function aren't triggered.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL);

client.connect();

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected');
});

const setJWT = (key, value) => {
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      console.log(key, value)
      return client.set(key, value, (error, response) => {
        
        if (error) reject(error);
        resolve(response);
        console.log("setJWT success");
        res.json(response);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a lot of things that don't look correctly, firstly you are referencing the variable res, but It doesn't exist in your code, also it's not necessary to wrap everything in a promise, you can use an async/await function, after your resolve or reject a promise the code finish, for that reason never the res.json code is executed, because the promise finished before that line of code, in this [link](https://medium.com/@agutierrezt/a-node-implementation-for-refresh-token-with-redis-a062020bbec0) you can see an example of redis in more details.

Comment: Thanks Andres! Great explanation. I rebuilt the function and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the new, working, version of the function:

```
  const setJWT = (key, value) => {
  try {
    client.set(key, value);
    console.log("setJWT success");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```